# Rails - Simplify WHERE condition IS NOT NULL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Working on a webpage I used the next line:

```
Model.select(:column).where("column IS NOT NULL")
```

I was wondering if there was a more Rails-ish way to do this, like using a hash for example

```
Model.select(:column).where(column: !nil)
```

Comment: Just as a side issue, you might consider whether the presence of a null value in the column can be avoided (and prevented by validation). They're something of a pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem will allow you to use != nil type syntax, but natively rails will not.

Example: `Model.where{column != nil}`

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use a scope as its more readable as well as its more manageable later (like merging with other scopes)

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :not_null, lambda { |column|
   {:select => column,
    :conditions => "#{column} NOT NULL"
    }
  }
end
```

then use

```
Model.not_null("column_name")
```

Comment: Are you suggesting making a separate scope for each column of each model??? Please show how this can be done in a more DRY way...

Comment: @Mischa, I updated my answer to get the column name as a parameter :)

Comment: That's better, but you still have to add it to every model you want to use it for.

Comment: @Mischa, for that you have two options, 1) add this code it to a module and include it (which I prefer) 2) re-open the ActiveRecord::Base and add the code there. However I think this requirement will not come everywhere, coz normally you should work with `Objects` not SQL results, in this case I prefer to get the objects which satisfy the requirements, not only the columns

Comment: Yeah, I would't put the `select` in the scope. Only the condition.

Answer (score 0):

In the Rails 4 you can do this:

```
Model.select(:column).where.not(column: nil)
```